# How to set checkbox with a certain value checked in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML elements:

```
<input class="type_checkbox" id="1" name="types[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="type_checkbox" id="0" name="types[]" type="checkbox" value="6">
```

I want to set checkbox true with jQuery where value is equal to 6. Pls help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector along with `prop()` to set the `checked` property.

```
$('input.type_checkbox[value="6"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You can obviously amend the `input.type_checkbox` part of the selector to better suit your needs.

Comment: if old Jquery version use .attr()

Comment: Thanks it worked, I have additional question. If I click on a link I want to set somehow that the id from link matches value from checkbox? $("a.type_link[id]").click(function (event) {$('input.type_checkbox[value="id"]').prop('checked', true);}

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You'd be best to start a new question for that, as there's a fair bit more logic involved.

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute equals selector:

```
$('input.type_checkbox[value=6]').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code,it should be worked

```
$(":checkbox[value=6]").prop("checked","true");
```

or

```
$("input[type=checkbox][value=6]").prop("checked",true);​
```